# High energy, low temperature?

Tags: science-based, planets, xenobiology

Alien spacecraft have entered orbit around Earth. They have launched a few probes for closer observations, but made no attempt to land. Figuring out meaningful communication is an ongoing process, but observations of the ships indicate that they seem to keep the interiors at around -150C and 20 atmospheres, flooded with nitrogen and traces of liquid oxygen. If that's the environment they prefer, no wonder they haven't tried to land! Earth would be like Mercury to them--way too hot, and practically no air!

Nevertheless, it is obvious that these aliens are animal-like creatures with access to a decent amount of metabolic energy for thinking (after all, they figured out how to build an interstellar spacecraft) and moving themselves around.

Given what we know so far, what can we extrapolate about the nature of their homeworld? What circumstances could keep a planetary surface that cold, end yet maximize the energy flux available to power an ecosystem that can support complex animals?

Comment: you may want to look at proposed helium 2 life.

Comment: Your 'around' qualifier needs to be qualified. At -160C and 20 bara, nitrogen is proably a liquid. I suspect your aliens are probably fish. Very brittle fish, in fact. Certainly not a DNA based life form. And definitely no metabolism, because even a very little amount of heat would boil the nitrogen. Pure intelligence, no substance. Perhaps ghosts or pure spirits. Now the question is, how could they manufacture a spaceship under those environmental conditions? Certainly no metal fabrication.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond The nature of the aliens themselves is not part of the question--just the nature of their homeworld. However, the nitrogen is indeed liquid, with a decent liquid range at the relevant pressures, but is *not* their internal biosolvent, and it does not bother them if it boils.

Comment: Ad: preowned cylinder tank comes with pressure gauge for beer dispensing and alien. Regulator sold separately.

Comment: @John Do you have references for that? Google is not helpful at finding reference to life using liquid helium.

Comment: it is from some larry niven stories, you may try superfluid helium instead.

Comment: @John Ah! I am familiar with Niven's Outsiders. They are pretty sketchy on details, though.

Comment: It is acutally from the draco tavern story, the slow ones, creatures show metabolic rate is millions of times slower than ours, a basic introduction takes decades.

Comment: @John "The Slow Ones" doesn't contain any mention of helium.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley I may be confusing two short stories,  I know it was a larry niven tail about organisms in extremely cold environments.

Comment: OOOps my bad. I thought your querry about ' power an ecosystem that can support complex animals?' would indicate that some understanding of the ecosystem and the complex animals would be required. Somehow, these aliens would have had to fabricate their spaceship in this enviromnet, and as we know, any manufacturing activity changes the environment considerably. Their home planet would be experiencing a particularly unique perspective on 'global warming', methinks.

Answer (score 6):

**The creatures are superconducting capacitors.  Biology on their world is electrical.**

The creatures require low temperature and high pressure to function as superconductors.  Their biology allows them to accumulate energy from voltage differentials in their environment, and store that energy in the perpetual current of the superconductor, releasing it as needed for action and metabolism.   Instead of fat, they store electrical energy.

Voltage differences occur everywhere.  I could imagine that the surface layer of a nonconductive [liquid nitrogen ocean](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/179323/appearance-of-a-nitrogen-sea) might accumulate charge (from the solar wind?  Or local weather?) just as the nonconductive surface of a balloon can accumulate charge.  The ancestral creatures might harvest these and other electrical charges from their environments, or consume creatures which themselves had harvested charge.  Although at the technology level they have reached they likely now generate charge artificially.

I envision their world as a rogue planet, long ago cut loose from its star and traveling alone through space. Liquid nitrogen oceans overlie the frozen water of the old oceans.  It would be like the rogue Earth described in Lieber's short story [A Pail of Air](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/51461).    I read that story when I was a little kid and the description of the lightning bolt stayed with me.  These creatures would love to find something like that, but they might need to team up on it.

---

Like the rogue earth except, of course, these creatures live in pressurized liquid nitrogen, not solid nitrogen under an airless black sky.  The planet therefore is a gas giant - except no longer gas.  As it cooled, the nitrogen layer of the atmosphere formed a circumplanetary ocean only a few km deep as nitrogen was a minor component of the original atmosphere.  The N2 ocean is compressed and insulated by the overlying liquid methane layer (and hydrogen / helium above that), and warmed from below by radiation from the core.  Perhaps the creatures are like whales, poking their heads out of the nitrogen sea (the top and bottom!) to take in resources that have accumulated at its interface with neighboring regions.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I think you can be sure is that its creatures have very long maturation times.  One issue with having lots of energy moving through an ecosystem but low temperatures is that this means you have to be very efficient.  If you are not efficient, you start to heat things up, raising the temperatures.  Your energy needs to remain organized, rather than letting entropy take hold of it and reduce it to heat.

Learning to do this takes a lot of time.  If these creatures don't have to deal with lots of energy turning into heat (like we do), that means they can fend off predators by posturing -- putting that energy on display without actually burning any of it.  A world where this is true is one where there is a lot of time for creatures to mature.  If there are fast-reproducing creatures, they would tend to consume the energy rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Earth receives some amount of power in the form of solar solar radiation, which it must also radiate away to maintain its current distribution of temperatures.

Of that, about 30% is reflected back into space (i.e., the Earth's average albedo is about 0.3), and about 1.5% is absorbed by plants to provide chemical energy to power the biosphere. (The Earth's biosphere also has inputs from geothermal energy, but that's basically a rounding error in comparison.)

Planetary surface temperature, ignoring the greenhouse effect, can be estimated by $T = \sqrt[4]{\frac{A_{abs}}{A_{rad}}P\frac{1-a}{\sigma\epsilon}}$, the $A$s are the effective absorption and emission areas, $P$ is areal power density (i.e., solar constant), $a$ is albedo, $\epsilon$ is emissivity, and $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant. Plugging in values for Earth, we get an effective temperature of around -20C; greenhouse effect makes up the difference, giving the Earth an actual average temperature of around 15C. In the alien environment, however, there aren't many greenhouse gasses that remain gaseous with significant vapor pressure, so I think we can largely ignore that.

Given exactly the same solar power input, and exactly the same amount of energy captured by plants, albedo could be increased significantly, thus reducing the amount of thermal emission the planet must maintain remain in equilibrium, and thus reducing the average temperature.

A reasonable estimated cap on planetary albedo is given by Europa, one of the most reflective objects in the solar system, with an albedo on 0.64. Making that change gets the effective temperature down to -55C--not far enough!

Since the capture of radiant energy by plants is so inefficient overall, however, the solar constant could be reduced considerably and maintain an equally energetic ecosystem if photosynthetic efficiency is increased. Actual photosynthetic efficiency on Earth is around 4.5%, while solar panels can be 20% efficient--and efficiency improves at lower temperatures. So, if the alien world has no increase in plant coverage, we could assume that their plant-equivalents are about 4.5 times more efficient than ours, and cut the solar constant proportionally.

That gets us down to -123C. Not quite there, but getting closer.

Now, on Earth we can support a human population on about one quarter acre per person. But, largely, we don't. The US feeds about 1.5 people per acre, and we don't use anywhere near all of our available land for farming. Thus, it seems reasonable that a civilization comparable to ours, run by naturally evolved biological animals powered by food produced by ecosystem powered by sunlight, could easily exist if every human (and every other predator, and every other herbivore) required, say, 3 times as much land area to support, corresponding to a proportional cut in the solar constant.

That gets us down to -159C, with a solar constant about 1/13th or 1/14th that of Earth's. That's good enough, including a margin for temperature variations across the world and possibly some amount of greenhouse effect.

With that assumed solar constant, if their homeworld orbit a sunlike star, it would orbit at about 3.7AU--in between Mars and Jupiter. Of course, it might also have a smaller orbit around a smaller star.

The observed traces of liquid oxygen in the alien's environment indicate that their native ecosystem probably also has access to oxygen in some form, and that they have an incentive to extract it. They probably "breathe" it, because otherwise, why would it be in their chosen environment? Oxygen tends to be highly toxic to organisms that don't use it. Thus, hydrogen probably isn't very available on their homeworld, or they would be hydrogen breathers instead. It would be surprising if there were no ammonia around, but the primarily source of hydrogen and oxygen is probably water ice, which would be a mineral on their world. Having plenty of water ice available would jive with having a very high albedo, as well. Perhaps the large amounts of nitrogen derive, at least in part, from biological destruction of ammonia to extract the hydrogen, like early Earth photosynthesizers used hydrogen sulfide before figuring out how to split water?

Despite being so cold, the world must therefore be small enough to not retain hydrogen gas. Thus, it could be slightly larger than Earth, but not much. Helium is almost certainly just as biologically inert for these aliens as it is for us, so I don't think we can tell whether the observed atmosphere is actually their native atmosphere, or if they've just neglected to add a helium component to their spacecraft atmospheres to avoid the complication. If it is their native atmosphere, their homeworld must have an escape velocity not much above 9m/s--which means it is smaller than Earth, or significantly less dense, or both. Having water ice as a major mineral component would also jive with lower density, and thus lower escape velocity. And it could conceivably be much smaller than Earth--say, around Mercury-sized. Surface gravity is thus probably somewhere between 1/3 and 1.5 times Earth's--if only the alien ships had rotating sections to observe! Given the much higher pressure, the alien homeworld must therefore have a much deeper atmosphere as well (the colder gasses will be more compressed, but still!), with strong Rayleigh scattering.

There is no methane detected in the alien ships, and the presence of oxygen means there's probably little or no methane in the alien homeworld's atmosphere, either--it would be destroyed by free oxygen. Presumably, any primordial methane has been destroyed or sequestered by biological processes. That means there's unlikely to be any kind of clouds, and very limited weather.

In summary, the alien homeworld is probably a terrestrial-sized planet, somewhere between the size of Mercury and a couple of Earth's, covered in a bright crust of dirty water ice, with a thick blue-ish atmosphere. Maybe there is an ocean of clear liquid nitrogen enveloping the entire world (more plausible if it's a large world, with suppressed topography)... or maybe there are distinct liquid nitrogen seas in which the aliens live (less plausible over all, but possible on a smaller world). The skies would be perpetually clear, and bright blue, with long twilights and deep red sunsets. While the sunlight is dim, it would still be brighter outside on the alien world than it is in most artificially-lit interior environments on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

## They are not "creatures" at all.

Space is vast, and it turns out that faster than light travel is either impossible, or not fast enough.

Generation ships invariably fail, if they are too small, or fall victims of their own success - their population decides that the mission is either meaningless or a myth, and adopt a "here and now" philosophy that is not conducive to further exploration, much less colonisation.

Cold sleep, hybernation, torpor, and so on all crash against either the unimaginable duration of a journey, or to unforeseen circumstances. Periodical revival and rotation of the crew is good for a few dozen of light-years, no more.

These aliens have mastered a different way: they upload themselves into electromechanical bodies, capable of "underclocking" until the centuries pass them by like minutes, and yet returning to full efficiency in a matter of instants should the need arise. Their ships are full of inert gas at high pressure as a shield against interstellar radiation; the oxygen contaminant (as well as hydrogen and carbon) is a byproduct of the interaction with said radiation.